# JS URL regex, allow only urls and empty string

Tags: javascript, regex, url-validation

I have the following regext:

```
var regex = /^(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;

function test() {
    alert(regex.test(document.getElementById("myinput").value));
}
```

I want to allow url or empty string.  **regex solution please**
How do I allow empty in this case?
https://jsfiddle.net/6kptovwc/2/
Thanks

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("myinput").value) == '') ........`

Comment: Why do you have a dot after `https://`?

Comment: `[a-z]{2,6}` is really short for TLD, see [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Comment: @Toto thanks for the inputs, noted. Anyway i was looking for a regex solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an alternation with empty string (I've simplified a bit your regex):

```
^((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*|)$
```

or

```
^((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[-\w@:%.+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b[-\w@:%+.~#?&\/=]*|)$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/basT53/1)

Comment: What do you think about my answer? (I have found a solution)

Comment: @SexyMF: Be aware that your regex is not anchored, it matches `blah blahwww.blah.com$*!§?#~´&²` for example, and the dot in `(http(s)?:\/\/.)` matches any character between the double slash and the url, for example `https://{subdomain.domain.com` another comment is avoid capture groups when yoou don't need to capture, prefer non capture group. Nevertheless if it works for you with all your test cases, that's fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Just add OR(||) condition**

```
function test() {
    const elm = document.getElementById("myinput")
    alert(elm.value === '' || regex.test(elm.value));
}
```

Comment: My code is just a demo. I asked for a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
^$|pattern
```

```
var regex = /^$|(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
```